# Phone makes sound when waving a credit card near it

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio, nfc

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and the phone was in my pocket. I forgot that my credit card was also in the same pocket and just out of nowhere my phone played the notification sound, so I pulled it out of my pocket and there were no notifications; no new email or SMS, nothing.

So then I pulled the card out and swiped it near the back of my phone, and then the sound played again. I did it like 20 times and it always happens. Why does my phone play the notification sound when I wave the credit card at the back of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your credit card have an NFC chip? The phone can read and write NFC data. It is probably activating Android Beam or S Beam.

Comment: Ohh, I forgot all about NFC. I didn't think we even had that in Australia yet. @mcrumly, does thing mean that we can find something online on our phones, and buy it with our cards by waving the card near our phone?

Comment: Probably not. But you can buy things with your phone at a store that accepts NFC payments. I don't know what is available in Australia,  but in the US I can pay using Google Wallet, Isis, and a few others.